# When including a .PDF, caption is not below .PDF when using /eject page-height change

Tags: graphics, captions, pdf, epstopdf

Consider the following MWE (you will need a **test.pdf** image to compile this).

This should compile using standard LaTeX. The problem is

- the caption is not below the .PDF image at all. It is on the next page.
- there is an extra page inserted before the image .PDF.

  ```
  \documentclass[]{memoir}

  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{caption}

  \usepackage{epstopdf}
  \epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.pdf}{png}{.png}{convert #1 \OutputFile}
  \AppendGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}

  \begin{document}

  \eject \pdfpagewidth=8.27in \pdfpageheight=21.5in

  \section{Vision}

  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{test.pdf}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption.}
  \end{center}

  \eject \pdfpagewidth=8.27in \pdfpageheight=11.69in

  \end{document}
  ```

  Please note that none of this weird behavior happens when using the following code (.PDF is here replaced by a dummy non-.PDF image):

  ```
  \documentclass[]{memoir}

  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{duckuments} 
  \usepackage{caption}

  \begin{document}

  \eject \pdfpagewidth=8.27in \pdfpageheight=21.5in

  \section{Vision}

  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption.}
  \end{center}

  \eject \pdfpagewidth=8.27in \pdfpageheight=11.69in

  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: well the graphics is too large and you are allowing a page break between the graphic and the caption. Use as recommended by the caption package a minipage to keep both together.

Comment: `\eject` isn't really a latex command (it is a left-over from plain tex) it shouldn't ever be used in a document.

Comment: why are you using epstopdf and converting to png to include a PDF ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer:

Wrapping it inside

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth}
```

will fix it.

Update after David's comment:

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
```

Comment: you don't need `[t]` or `1` but you probably need `\noindent` otherwise the minipage will be indented and will not fit in the page.  Finally this will prevent a page break but the page will be over-full unless you also enlarge the text area on the page.